# Why I am unable to submit the form in adminhtml using custom block in publichtml?

Tags: magento2

Instead of edit page I am using a simple file upload form using a block:

upload_form.phtml

```
<form method="POST" action="<?=$block->getUrl("/test/uploadcsv");?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="emailcsv_uploadform" type="file" name="upload_csv">
    <button type="submit">Upload File</button>
</form>
```

That is loaded from this template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block  name="pcmagas.test.uploadform" class="Pcmagas\Test\Block\Adminhtml\UploadForm" template="upload_form.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

```
namespace Pcmagas\Test\Block\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class UploadForm extends Template
{

}
```

And the controller that I use to handle the upload is the following:

```
namespace Pcmagas\Test\Controller\Adminhtml\Test;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;

class Uploadcsv extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute action based on request and return result
     *
     * @return ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
     * @throws NotFoundException
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getFiles();
        die("Psofisa"); // Debug code

        return "LALALA";
    }
}
```

Using the following `etc/adminhtml/routes.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route frontName="csvupload" id="csvupload">
            <module before="Magento_Backend" name="Pcmagas_Test"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

But whilst I submit the form I am redirected into magento's adminhtml frontpage instead of breaking the submition upon the `die`.

Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's another approach change the block into:

```php
namespace Pcmagas\Test\Block\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class UploadForm extends Template
{
    protected $formKey;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        parent::__construct($context,$data);
    }

    public function getFormKey()
    {
        return $this->formKey->getFormKey();
    }
}
```

Then upon phtml place another input field named `form_key`:

```html
<form method="POST" action="<?=$block->getUrl("/test/uploadcsv");?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="emailcsv_uploadform" type="file" name="upload_csv">
    <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?=$block->getFormKey();?>">
    <button type="submit">Upload File</button>
</form>
```

Then make the controller implement the `Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface` as well:

```php
namespace Pcmagas\Test\Controller\Adminhtml\Test;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;

class Uploadcsv extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action implements HttpPostActionInterface
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute action based on request and return result
     *
     * @return ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
     * @throws NotFoundException
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getFiles();
        die("Psofisa"); // Debug code

        return "LALALA";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Block class must be extended backend template class (Magento\Backend\Block\Template).**

```
<?php

namespace Pcmagas\Test\Block\Adminhtml;

class UploadForm extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
    protected $formKey;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getFormKey()
    {
        return $this->formKey->getFormKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For the backend :-**

**update the action** `<?=$block->getUrl("/csvupload/test/uploadcsv");?>`

====================================================================

**For the frontend:-**

Please use `standard` instead of `admin` from `routes.xml` file.

Replace from :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route frontName="csvupload" id="csvupload">
            <module before="Magento_Backend" name="Pcmagas_Test"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Replace to :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="csvupload" id="csvupload">
            <module name="Pcmagas_Test"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

clear and flush the Magento cahce.

Comment: But the form in Admin Panel and I want to be displayed in it.

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: use  <?=$block->getUrl("/csvupload/test/uploadcsv");?>  for backend action